# Is there a library or tutorial in creating a report designer

Tags: java

My Company is asking me to create a report generator. Seems easy enough as of itself, but the catch is that it has to be dynamic.

It has to be dynamic in such a way that we don't need to program anymore when there are new report formats. After some research, I have come across to many solutions, but none of them really fit my criteria.

I have come across Jasper reports and tried their Jaspersoft Studio. This was what I was looking for, but it's too technical. I needed to skin it so that normal users can use it. This approach is, of course, a bit of a scumbag move. So I was thinking of just using this as inspiration and follow its UI.

But in all my research I fail to find the "Report Designer Area" as you call it, where you drag and drop the components.

I was able to see that it uses XML, but that means that I will need to research on Drag-and-drop to XML Generation, but there has to be an easier way.

I'm ok with drag and drop coding, UI designing, Dynamic Queries... All that. I'm OK with the rest, my only problem of now is how do I create the report designer, where people drag and drop the components.

How do I create that pixelated paper at the center of it all where people put in the Labels, Datas, Borders, All that.

For now, my base code is reliant on JavaFX instead of Java Swing or SWT Libraries.

Comment: I would like to be enlightened on why this is moved to SoftRec? I was looking for Programming advice/Basic Source code/libraries, not actual made software.

Comment: Ask why on [Meta.Prog.SE](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/). Since this was migrated to a beta site it had to have been migrated by a moderator (that and the only place we can vote to migrate is SO anyway).

Comment: While [asking for libraries is fully OK here at SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/8/185), we don't provide tutorials or the like. The scope of this site is to recommend specific software to your named requirements. To prevent your question from being "put down", I strongly recommend you [edit] it to meet this site's scope. For a guide, please check [this Meta question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185).